# How to update the PRIMARY KEY/FOREIGN KEY in other related tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

walls

- wall_id (P)
- wall_name
- wall_views
- wall_downloads
- wall_thumbnail_path

(`4, 'wall4', '125', '574', '../.../thumbnail_wall4.jpg'`)

types

- type_id
- type_name

(`'1', 'Desktop'`)
(`'2', 'Phone'`)
(`'3', 'Tablet'`)

wall_types

- wall_id (P) (F)
- type_id (P) (F)

(`4, 1`)

Above are the tables I have, what I want to do is automatically get the `wall_id = 4` from `walls` tables and store it in `wall_types` table, same with the `type_id` from `types` table. How can this be done? what is the code (PHP code) or SQL statements to achieve this? thanks!

Note:

- `wall_id` in `wall_types` references `wall_id` in `walls` table.
- `type_id` in `types` references `type_id` in `types` table.

Comment: What do you mean by automatically? You always need to know which type_id you need before you can insert in in the wall_types table. That value needs to come from somewhere (user input for example), so i don't know what you mean by automatically?

Comment: the value of wall_id in walls table will come from the walls table itself since its AUTO INCREMENT, so if the previous record is with wall_id = 4 the next will be wall_id = 5 which I want to add to wall_types table and the type will be specified by the uploader by selecting the checkbox

Comment: so if the uploader selected Desktop as the type, it will take 1 from types table and store it in wall_types along with wall_id = 5 so the new record would be (5, 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below inserts a new relation in your wall_types table, where '1' comes from user input (user selected 'Desktop'):

```
INSERT INTO wall_types (wall_id, type_id) VALUES (5,1);
```

If you want to do this right after you inserted a new 'wall' row where the id is (off course) unknown yet, you can use LAST_INSERT_ID(), this will contain the last inserted id, therefore you need to execute this query right after the 'wall' insert query:

```
INSERT INTO wall_types (wall_id, type_id) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),1);
```

Comment: You can execute this right after the query where your walls row is added.

Comment: sort of like that..since I'll be updating the tables with one script. Is this the most effective solution?

Comment: Yes i think it is! There is no really need to create a mysql trigger for this, it's a bit overkill for what you want and this makes you better understand what is happening.

Comment: can I use consecutive queries with LAST_INSERT_ID() since I'll be updating several other tables with same wall_id?

Comment: LAST_INSERT_ID() gives you the last inserted id (primary key) in your database. So if you're performing another query after it, it might be overwritten. In that case, you can store the id in a php variable with mysql(i)_insert_id (see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this "automatically" you can use Triggers to update the relashionship.
The other way is remove the relationship in wall_types and re-create with the updated values.